# Json request text not well formed

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm using angularjs to make my first web application.

I'm retreiving data from server as JSON object, and i'm trying to display in HTML page. The json objet looks like :

```
{
"title":"news1",
"description":"La fédération du <strong>Malawi<\/strong> n’a pas trop attendu pour remercier le sélectionneur <strong>Young Chimodzi<\/strong> après la défaite à domicile face au <strong>Zimbabwe.<\/strong>\ <br\/>\ <br\/>Le technicien local a été placé en congés jusqu’à la fin de son contrat qui expire à la fin de juillet prochain. La raison est simple, la défaite surprise face au Zimbabwe 1-2 lors de la première journée de la phase éliminatoire de la Coupe d’Afrique des nations Orange 2017.\ <br\/>\ <br\/>L’instance du pays a annoncé qu’un successeur à <strong>Young Chimodzi<\/strong> sera nommé le 1er aout prochain. Alors que l’intérim sera assuré par <strong>Ernest Mtawali.<\/strong>\" 

}
```

I'm using a simple ng-repeat to dislay text :

```
<div ng-rpeat="n in news">
<p>{{n.description}}</p>
</div>
```

I'm using a simple json request :

```
 $http.get("http://www.server/news", {headers:  {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }, })
        .success(function (response) {

            $scope.news = response;

        });
```

I tried to change the content type and to play with it but no changes

the text is not well formed it's showing like that :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to render the html. For that you need angular sanatize library.

Add angular-sanatize.js in your html, and in your module add dependency of ngSanatize.

And update your html to

```
<p ng-bind-html="n.description"></p>
```

For details, refer to - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: Thank you so much ! it works I will accept your answer in some minutes

Comment: Good to know that. I was also stating the same thing.